# No route matches /signout when i disable javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To signing out a user i have the link :

```
link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete"
```

this link work fine and i have already a route /signout in my routes file, but when i disable javascript and click this link it says : **No route matches [GET] "/signout"**, what's the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without scripting, browsers can only send a non-GET request by submitting a form -- clicking a link is always a GET. When you specify a different method for `link_to`, it adds a JavaScript hook to the link that dynamically creates and submits a form with the appropriate method. If scripting is disabled, the browser just submits a GET request as it normally would. [This is explained in the docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) (look under **Options**).

If your app needs to support users with scripting disabled, you can use [`button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) instead of `link_to`, and style the button to look like a link.